# stunnel4 Error. INTERNAL ERROR: Bad magic at ssl.c, line 117

Tags: vpn, openvpn, stunnel

stunnel4 Error. INTERNAL ERROR: Bad magic at ssl.c, line 117. when restart stunnel4 service then solve issue, but after some time face again issue.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has been reported:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/stunnel4/+bug/1847275

It still hasn't been fixed.  See here for a workaround.

https://scottiestech.info/2020/06/23/fix-stunnel-bad-magic-at-ssl-c-error-crash-on-ubuntu/